# How to bring mp3 file information on jplayer

Tags: jquery, mp3

I need to bring the mp3 file information like Artist, Album, Who sung the song, Title etc on **Jplayer**.How can i bring this. Please give me link if there is any tutorial on this.

Comment: Doesn't look to me as if that plugin is designed to deal with any sort of stream metadata at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Javascript, you will need a server side language or client side plugin to determine the ID3 information of your MP3 file. However, another option is to store these along in a database when you upload your music which removes the need for reading the ID3 tags...

Comment: i m not storing any records in database. wat is that client side plugin. Right now i m using Jquery audio player.

Comment: @selva: That's not what I'm saying. A client side plugin like Flash, Java or Silverlight to obtain the ID3 tag or some server side script that could do that. Your jQuery Audio Player does not allow ID3 metadata to be read...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/) might help.

(It is not complete solution as you still need to populate jPlayer's playlist. However it will do the tricky part of getting ID tags without any additional help from the server side)